# Access web project in a mobile phone

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web project in my pc. It's running on `http://localhost:54331/Default.aspx`. Also, there's an another pc in my local network and a mobile phone. How can I access this asp.net project from these devices? The project only loaded one pc. How to do this?

Comment: What ?!?! You need to explain better... what do you mean by *access my project* ? The web site that is run by your project? The actual project and source code files ???

Comment: The actual project and source code files is in my pc. i want to open this project in a browser from a mobile phone.

Comment: Then host your project's web site in IIS - give it a proper virtual directory - and then access that site from your other devices using that URL .....

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Development server doesn't allow remote access to hosted web apps. Use IIS (Express or full edition)